# Why the negative sign in modified duration relationship

Tags: fixed-income, bond, duration

If $P$ is price, $D$ modified duration and $y$ yield then we have the relationship,

$$dP=-D \cdot P \cdot dy$$

Why is there a minus sign and what does correspond to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The price-yield relationship is negatively correlated; when prices go down, the implied yield goes up. The minus sign allows the modified duration to be positive for a normal bond.